# Bash: can I have shell autocompletion ignore certain paths?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have some directories in my home directory which I prefer to leave as-named, for various reasons.  They do however irritate me as I basically *never* need to autocomplete on them, and they interfere with my programmed `tab` autocompletion.

Is there someway I can tell bash to ignore these paths when I hit tab for autocompletion?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour) is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

Comment: Point taken.  I am however doing the autocompletion as part of my programming tasks, for what that's worth.